# Error installing GDBM 1.10

Tags: linux, gdbm

First, i did ./configure

Then, i did make install and Terminal show this:

make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lucas/Área de Trabalho/gdbm-1.10/src'

test -z "/usr/local/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib"
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libgdbm.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgdbm.so.4.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libgdbm.so.4.0.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libgdbm.so.4.0.0': Permission denied

make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lucas/Área de Trabalho/gdbm-1.10/src'

make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lucas/Área de Trabalho/gdbm-1.10/src'

make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have permissions to write to /usr/local/lib

`sudo make install`

or become root and run `make install`